# Is there any way to recover data from 2nd SD partition?

Tags: sd-card, mount, link2sd

From the beginning. I was using Link2SD in order to save up some internal memory, but today I noticed that all apps moved to to second partition (EXT2) magically disappeared. I don't want to repair Link2SD because I'm going to change phone very soon. I want to recover data from **/data/sdext2**, but i can't mount it. I want to recover this data because I change SDCard too. Link2SD saying something about invalid argument during creating mount script. Is there any way to access this data so far? Or I must say goodbye to them?

PS. First partition is safe and sound. It works great.

Comment: Looks like it's not damaged at all. The app itself went wrong somewherr.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To access second partition on SD card `if it's not deleted`, you may adopt multiple approaches listed below. For deleted partitons or deleted files, you may use tools like [`testdisk`](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) and `extundelete` which doesn't seem to be the case here.

### LINUX / WINDOWS

As mentioned by @iBug, you can remove SD card from phone and insert in a PC with `Linux` OS like Ubuntu. You will be able to access both partitions there. File browsers like `Nautilus` and `Dolphin` by default show all formatted partitions in left panel on newly inserted media.
In order to directly mount a partition from Android device to Linux PC, you can expose it as a `USB Mass Storage` device. By default [UMS is disabled on newer devices](https://www.xda-developers.com/diving-into-sdcardfs-how-googles-fuse-replacement-will-reduce-io-overhead/) but can be enabled by a [little hacking](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=75354223&postcount=16).

**Windows** by default only mounts first accessible partition on SD cards and other removable media. However, if you want to access second partition on Windows, it is possible. You need to make SD card a `local hard disk` drive using a hacked driver like [`Cfadisk usb driver`](http://www.etcwiki.org/wiki/Cfadisk_usb_driver). Follow [this link](https://superuser.com/questions/975900/sd-card-second-partition-not-recognized) for detailed guide.

### ACCESS 2nd PARTITION FROM ANDROID

Some custom builds of `TWRP` auto-mount SD card second partition under something like `/sd-ext` etc. If not so, you can mount it yourself in Android `recovery` or `ROM`, as you seem to have already rooted device.

1. Reboot in TWRP recovery and use built-in terminal app there. Or if you want to do it from ROM, install terminal emulator app like [`Terminal Emulator`](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jackpal.androidterm) if you don't have one already. Third option is to use `adb`, in ROM  or in recovery.
2. Find how kernel names `block devices` on your phone:

   ```
   ~# ls /dev/block/
   ```

   You will find a number of devices there. On a typical `Qualcomm` device, `mmcblk0` will be representing internal memory i.e. eMMC and `mmcblk1` will be representing external SD card. Though there will be many other internal partitions and loop devices, we are concerned with three entries of external SD card:

   ```
   mmcblk1    mmcblk1p1    mmcblk1p2
   ```

   Here `mmcblk1p2` is the second partition on SD card.
3. For confirmation:

   ```
   ~# fdisk /dev/block/mmcblk1p2
   ```

   This will show details about SD card second partition including `size`.
4. Mount partition:

   ```
   ~# mkdir /sd_ext
   ~# mount -o ro /dev/block/mmcblk1p2 /sd_ext
   ```

   First command will create a directory `sd_ext` under your root which you may access from any `file explorer` or command-line. `ro` option in second command will mount the partition `read-only` so that you may not harm any data accidentally. You may eliminate this.
   If not successful, you may need to specify `filesystem` yourself what you used at the time of partitioning:

   ```
   ~# mount -t ext4 -o ro /dev/block/mmcblk1p2 /sd_ext
   ```

   To know which filesystem a partition has:

   ```
   ~# blkid /dev/block/mmcblk1p2
   ```

   There are many other tools that can be used for the purpose like `parted`, `fsck` and `tune2fs` etc. but these might not be necessarily available.
5. Mounted partition will be `un-mounted` automatically on reboot. You can do this manually:

   ```
   ~# umount /sd_ext
   ```

***NOTE:***

1. Be cautious not to touch second partition on internal memory which may belong to bootloader. Or you may brick your phone.
2. All commands used above need `root access` and binaries are included in TWRP. You may install `busybox` in ROM if any command not found.

**RELATED:**

- [How disk space is partitioned in an Android phone?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/201224/218526)
- [Why can't I see Android storage as a partition on PC?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/205559/218526)
- [How to mount Internal Storage as USB Mass Storage for recovering data?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/205596/218526)
- [How to fix USB Mass Storage not recognized by PC?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/205613/218526)
- [How to recover a deleted file from /data partition?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/208114/218526)
- [How to take full image backup of eMMC?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/203913/218526)

Answer (score 1):

Remove the card from your phone and plug it into a computer running a Linux system (like Ubuntu or Fedora). You'll easily be able to access data on that card.

Comment: I'll easily be able to access both partitions?

Comment: Yes, of course.