# Sd card COMPLETELY unrecognizable after rooting

Tags: sd-card, root-access

Around a year ago, I rooted my Samsung Galaxy Tab T-113. I cannot find the respective rooting thread anymore, so I cannot provide any links :/

I do remember that the thread told me from the start, that the external sd card (Sandisk class 4 32GB, used for rooting) would be locked to the device after rooting it.

The external sd card functioned without any issues for a while, until the device got into a bootloop. I restored the device to factory settings after which the sd card became unreadable, not even recognized as corrupt by the device.

I then tried formatting the sd card through Windows, but Windows doesn't recognize my sd card either.. no sound, no cards in device manager. It can't even be recognized by other phones/laptops (tried multiple)

Is anyone aware of any rooting tools which actually locked the sd card to the device? I'm trying to find the method, in order to find a solution..

Or does anyone know how I can retrieve the data from the sd card? (maybe through additional purchasable hardware for sd card recoveries?

Thanks in advance! :)

P.s: the sd card was never exposed to extreme temperatures or water.

Comment: Sounds like the card malfunctioned. Most likely it has nothing to do with the device or root.

Comment: See if the solutions here help in recognising SD https://android.stackexchange.com/q/190820/131553

Comment: Can you access the SD card using a computer or some other device?

Answer (score 0):

If your pc doesn't see sd card but you are able to hear a sound when connecting to the pc then you have a chance of recovery. Try to connect via USB adapter and first go to your pc didn't management. If you can see your sd card there then you just make it visible. If you can't see through disc  management then log in to your bios and see if you can see your sd card there. Also try to use other port. If you can see via bios then you need to create  another usb with Windows restoration environment or create bootable USB with command line in order to be able to perform file check command. I don't know how advanced you are in these things. If don't feel comfortable doing this then perhaps you need to ask some tech. If you think you can do it yourself then check first whether you are able to see it as I have mentioned.   Also try to create bootable USB with Linux on it and boot your pc into USB with Linux on it. If you can see your sd then just work in Linux virtual environment.  Sorry may seem a bit complicated but it's the way it is.