# Phone doesn't see SDCard after doing 2nd partition

Tags: external-sd, sd-card, 7.0-nougat, partitions

In [this topic](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/190820/is-there-any-way-to-recover-data-from-2nd-sd-partition) I mentioned that I'm going to change a phone. And it happened. I bought new SDCard and inserted it into new phone. My new Samsung saw this card perfectly. Using **MiniTool Partition Wizard** I made a 2nd partition for Link2SD. Before partitioning there was 16MB unallocated memory at the beginning and 59,6GB Primary exFAT partition (I bought 64GB card). After partitioning I have 51,6GB Primary exFAT partition (1st partition for music, images etc.) and 8,0GB Primary EXT2 partition (2nd partition for apps). After partitioning my phone can't see the card completely. Just like it hasn't be inserted. But after returning to old partition everything works fine again. How to fix it? Note that my new phone is **Samsung Galaxy J3 2017** powered by Android Nougat 7.0.