# How to fix USB Mass Storage not recognized by PC?

Tags: usb-mass-storage

I have tried many things but can't make my Samsung Galaxy mini 2 S6500 USB Mass Storage to be simply recognized by my PC. Why is such a simple thing so hard?
Does anyone know the solution to this problem?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you have Samsung USB drivers installed? Also some models don't support mass storage but MTP instead.

Comment: Duplicate of [How to mount Internal Storage as USB Mass Storage for recovering data?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/199536/how-to-mount-internal-storage-as-usb-mass-storage-for-recovering-data)